# JQuery POST request transforming into OPTIONS. Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, response

I explicitly specify a POST and I don't see the post data in the Request and more over specifies it has a OPTIONS.

The response should be a HTML specifying matching users to Query in table format. 
I am trying to post and read the html to create a auto-complete input box.

This the Jquery Code:

```
$.post('https://internal.company.com/data/displayUserList',
    { Email: "", Name: "%GEORGE%"}, 
    function(responseText, textStatus) {
        console.log("Response:\n" + responseText + textStatus)
    }
);
```

Request captured by FireBug1.6.1 (Firefox)

```
OPTIONS /data/displayUserList HTTP/1.1
Host: internal.company.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/3.6.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: null
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
```

Comment: There are many related questions about that in issue in jQuery on SE. See "Related" Possible solution are discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could happen if you violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction. The `Access-Control-Request-Method` request header makes me think this is the case. I see that you specify a full address `https://internal.company.com/data/displayUserList` in your post request. Make sure that the page hosting this script is originating from `https://internal.company.com` as well. The best would be to use a relative address:

```
$.post('/data/displayUserList', { Email: "", Name: "%GEORGE%" }, 
    function(responseText, textStatus) {
        console.log("Response:\n" + responseText + textStatus);
    }
);
```

Comment: Yes. I am trying to post the URL in another webpage, but there top domain is same "company.com", I will check if "document.domain" is same. Also I noticed there are few cookie information sent when "https://internal.company.com/data/displayUserList" is triggered from the browser. Is there a way I could capture them and send it with this request?

Comment: Is the protocol the same? Note that HTTP vs HTTPS violates the same origin policy. As far as cookies are concerned, they will be automatically sent along the AJAX request if those cookies have been set with a domain property equal to the top domain so that they can be shared between those domains.

Comment: Yes, protocol is HTTPS. I noticed cookies are not picked up apart from OPTIONS issue. Should I change anything in the call?

Comment: @hashg, domains must match: `https://internal.company.com` and `https://company.com` are not the same and violate the policy. Please look at the wikipedia article I've linked to in my answer and make sure that the domain and subdomain match exactly. Otherwise your AJAX call will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to call a different server in another domain then the strategy to overcome this should reside in the backend to make the server to allow calls from a different front-end domain and in that case you shouldn't break your head trying to adjust this in the front end.