# Calling WCF service from multiple domain clients

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, json

I have a WCF service that I access fram Javascript using AJAX and JSON. The client and the service is on the same site (domanin). It works great.

I now need to call the same service from several other sites/domains. How is this done? So far I have not found any resources describing this scenario.

These sites uses ASP.NET 4.0 (C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that you need JSONP but I don't agree with using custom behavior from WCF 3.5 samples. WCF 4 has a [native support for JSONP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.crossdomainscriptaccessenabled.aspx) by turning on `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled` in the `webHttpBinding` configuration. I wrote an [example in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686059/how-to-avoid-cross-domain-policy-in-jquery-ajax-for-consuming-wcf-service/5686254#5686254).

Comment: Thanks, Ladislav. The `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled` led me to this great article, http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery/.

Answer (score 0):

you need use [jsonp](http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/).