# why web service can't be accessed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

When i try to access web service from the development server, it returns the error below.
When I access the same service from my local machine, it works fine.
Do you have idea what might be the reason?
Thank you very much in advance!

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Portal.ExportSvcReference.IExportDataService.AddDataRequest(ExportData request)
```

Comment: has the method signatures changed?

Comment: no, the method signatures didnt change.

Comment: it it the same code for the web service in the same place. just different locations of the same as code website are calling it.

Comment: How are you calling the WCF service?

Comment: If the service is deployed but your client script is still running on localhost, you might have run into cross domain issues. See this answer here for how to enable cross domain access: stackoverflow.com/questions/5686059/how-to-avoid-cross-domain-policy-in-jquery-ajax-for-consuming-wcf-service

Comment: Can you compare the configs on the test server to the one that works, think the issue is most likely to lie in the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

405 errors are often caused by cross domain issues. If you've deployed your service, but are testing from a client on localhost (or on another deployment), then everything is no longer running under the same localhost domain, so you need to enable cross domain calls.

A good example of enabling cross-domain scripting can be found here:
[how to avoid cross domain policy in jquery ajax for consuming wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686059/how-to-avoid-cross-domain-policy-in-jquery-ajax-for-consuming-wcf-service)

As @Monkieboy says, it's a little hard to diagnose without seeing your web.config file, but try chaging whichever binding you are using by adding `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"` and see if that helps.