# 405 Method Not Allowed - when sending object from jQuery to rest WCF

Tags: c#, jquery, rest, wcf

This question is asked a lot, but even though I tried the solutions they offered, I still get an error.

I am sending a post request with a Person object as a parameter, but i get:

> 405 - Method Not Allowed error"

code:

contract:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IPayMentService
 {
      [OperationContract]
      [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
          UriTemplate = "/AddPerson",
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
      void AddPerson(Person person); 
 }

 [DataContract]
 public class Person
 {
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }
 }
```

service:

```
public class PayMentService : IPayMentService
{
    public void AddPerson(Person person) 
    {
        //..logic
    }
}
```

client:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var person = {Id: 1, Age : 13, Name: "zag"};

  $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:64858/PayMentService.svc/AddPerson',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(person),
        dataType: 'json'
    })
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using IIS?

Comment: I am using IIS express

Comment: Possible duplicate of [405 Error upon moving MVC 4 application and WCF service to IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984342/405-error-upon-moving-mvc-4-application-and-wcf-service-to-iis-8)

Comment: Please try _every_ suggestion in the duplicate before saying the duplicate doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code in the global.asax file:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
           HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
           HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Option request doesn't return suitable status, the request will also fail.
To ensure option request returns 200 status, you had better change the status code.
You could also add these headers in web.config.

```
 <system.webServer>

  <httpProtocol>  
  <customHeaders>  
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />  
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>
        </customHeaders>  
</httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

  protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                 if(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        }

    }
```

If you are not familiar with cross region request, you could refer to mdn

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS