# Callback function for JSONP with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I didn't quite understand how to work with the callback for the ajax function of jQuery.

I have the following code in the JavaScript:

```
try {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://url.of.my.server/submit?callback=?',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#survey").serialize(),
        dataType: "jsonp",
        timeout: 200,
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
        success: function (data, status) {
            mySurvey.closePopup();
        },
        error: function (xOptions, textStatus) {
            mySurvey.closePopup();
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    mySurvey.closePopup();
}
```

And on the server side (AppEngine / Python) I get the value of the callback parameter and respond with

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
self.response.out.write(callback + '({"msg": "ok"});')
```

But then I get an `"Error: jQuery152042227689944248825_1317400799214 is not a function"` in the browser console.

What is the proper way to handle this? Right now I get the results that I need, but the fact that I know it's not right is bothering me.

Comment: I guess the POST parameter is ignored. As I know JSONP can only make GET requests because what actually does is creating a <script> tag in the head section of you page and retrieve the resource as it was a generic js file stored on another server.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is what I do on mine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#userForm').valid()) {
    var formData = $("#userForm").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.example.com/user/' + $('#Id').val() + '?callback=?',
      type: "GET",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback"
    });
  });

function localJsonpCallback(json) {
  if (!json.Error) {
    $('#resultForm').submit();
  } else {
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#userForm').show();
    alert(json.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: @vsync, you cannot do a post with jsonp. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp

Answer (score 13):

delete this line:

```
jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
```

Or replace this line:

```
url: 'http://url.of.my.server/submit?callback=json_callback',
```

because currently you are asking jQuery to create a random callback function name with `callback=?` and then telling jQuery that you want to use `jsonp_callback` instead.

Answer (score 11):

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://url.of.my.server/submit',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonp_callback'
    });
```

**jsonp** is the querystring parameter name that is defined to be acceptable by the server while the **jsonpCallback** is the javascript function name to be executed at the client.
When you use such url:

```
url: 'http://url.of.my.server/submit?callback=?'
```

the question mark ? at the end instructs jQuery to generate a random function while the predfined behavior of the autogenerated function will just invoke the callback -the sucess function in this case- passing the json data as a parameter.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://url.of.my.server/submit?callback=?',
        success: function (data, status) {
            mySurvey.closePopup();
        },
        error: function (xOptions, textStatus) {
            mySurvey.closePopup();
        }
    });
```

The same goes here if you are using $.getJSON with ? placeholder it will generate a random function while the predfined behavior of the autogenerated function will just invoke the callback:

```
$.getJSON('http://url.of.my.server/submit?callback=?',function(data){
//process data here
});
```

Comment: "the autogenerated function will just invoke the callback", Thanks!

Comment: Abdelfattah Ragab thank you a lot for explaining this!