# getJSON's fail event not being called when internet drops

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer, cross-domain-policy

I am running a single webpage 24/7 on two computers. One computer is running `IE8`, the other `IE9`. On this webpage is a javascript timer which runs `$.getJSON` to retrieve a `cross-domain` JSON object. The `$.getJSON` works perfectly under normal conditions however there is the possibility that the internet connection on one of these computers will go down temporarily. Since I am using the `$.getJSON` to retrieve new content for the webpage, if the internet goes down momentarily, the old content will be shown.

My issue is that I assumed `$.getJSON`'s `fail` event would fire if the internet went down when the `$.getJSON` was called. In this case, a new timer would be set to attempt to retrieve the `JSON` in X minutes (it will never stop trying). When testing this, I disabled my internet connection and yet the code within the `fail` event did not fire.

Will `fail` not be called in the case of no internet connection? If so, what would you recommend to prevent my JavaScript from stopping permanently when the internet goes down?

(One method I looked at was checking for an internet connection before the JSON call however I've read `window.navigator.onLine` is unreliable and I couldn't find any other solutions)

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238619/getjson-timeout-handling

Comment: Or you can add an "isoffline" callback with a library like this: http://nouincolor.com/heyoffline.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getJSON` is just shorthand for `ajax` with a few values already set. And `ajax` has a `timeout` option. That is probably the most reliable option (but obviously won't respond to network failure immediately). I personally would combine it with any checks you can find for determining network status.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    timeout: 10000 // 10 seconds
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Actually, in your specific case, just set the timeout to whatever retry interval you want, and have the error handler retry the request (if the error was a timeout) directly, or with a `setTimeout('tryAgainFunction()',0)` (not sure how jQuery works internally, but without that you might get an ever-increasing memory footprint).

Comment: Why put `tryAgainFunction()` in a timeout?

Comment: On the `JQuery` website it says this under the `error` function for `AJAX`: "This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests." This is true for `fail` as well?

Comment: It's to do with variable scope. As I understand it, `function a(){var i;a()}` will create more and more `i` variables as it loops, but `function a(){var i;setTimeout('a()',0)}` will only have the last one (using quotes puts the called function into an `eval` environment which doesn't inherit scoped variables). `function a(){var i;setTimeout(a,0)}` *will* create more `i` variables. Whether you need it or not depends on how jQuery handles things internally.

Comment: @noahnu You're not using JSONP or script requests, so don't worry about that.

Comment: @noahnu calling something with `setTimeout(..., 0)` basically schedules it to be called as soon as javascript is idle. This allows the current function to return. If you call a method directly, the current function does not return until the called function returns, which makes the call stack deeper.

Comment: In this case I don't think the `setTimeout(..., 0)` is necessary because the `error` handler will get called with a "fresh" call stack -- the call stack would not include the code that called `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Works, thanks. Would you recommend I call the function again regardless of the nature of the error?

Comment: Only if you delay it a few seconds, otherwise you could easily DDOS yourself. Also it's generally considered good practice to increase the wait time as the number of failures increases; first waits (maybe) 1 second, then 2, then 4, 8, etc. With some eventual cap (maybe at 2 minutes).