# I can't retrieve data from my api link with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Before i retrieve data from my link (http://mubi-app.herokuapp.com/api/v1/home), i test it with browser, it is ok. it returns Json format, but i got error when i access that link with ajax. 
Thanks,

Here is my code .....

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET"
    , url:"http://mubi-app.herokuapp.com/api/v1/home"
    , dataType:"jsonp"
    , success: function(data){
        debugger;

        $('#result').text(data)

    } 
   , error: function(e) {
       debugger;
       console.log(e)
       alert(e + "Error");
       }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Did you try to get the log on server side?

Comment: Is the call to server side made?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a cross-domain request you are trying to use jsonp request, but for that to work the server needs to support it. In this case it does not seem to be the case.

So I don't think it is possible to create a browser side call to the said API.

One possible solution is to write a server side wrapper for the said API, can in server side delegate the request to the said API.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `jsonpcallback function` to solve your issue, like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET"
    , url:"http://mubi-app.herokuapp.com/api/v1/home"
    , dataType:"jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback",
     success: function(data){
        debugger;

        $('#result').text(data)

    } 
   , error: function(e) {
       debugger;
       console.log(e)
       alert(e + "Error");
       }
    });
});

function localJsonpCallback(json) {
    console.log(json);
}
```

Read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613815/callback-function-for-jsonp-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I try as Rohan Kumar said, i got this error in console "
SyntaxError: invalid label
{"status":1,"movies":[{"id":1,"name":"Irma Crona","cinemas":["

Comment: Can you change the `key name` **status** to **mystatus** on http://mubi-app.herokuapp.com/api/v1/home page, if yes then do that and check.