# jQuery.AJAX uses GET instead of POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have a really simple HTML page running jQuery that's trying to post to a REST API. Here's my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var user = 'someuser';
    var pass = 'somepassword';
    var payload = {
        "value1": "first value",
        "value2": "second value"
    };
    var rootUrl = 'http://someinternalserver:8888/api/Method';
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" id="postWtnBlock">
    function postValue_Go() {
        $.ajax({
            url: rootUrl,
            // Removing the next line or changing the value to 'JSON' results in an OPTIONS request.
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            method: 'POST',
            user: user,
            password: pass,
            beforeSend: function (req) {
                req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'BASIC ' + btoa(user + ':' + pass));
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Two things are happening here.

1) Every request is being sent as a GET request, not a POST.
2) The Authorization Header never makes it into the request; it's always missing.

I have no idea why this is.

**Update #1:** The new postValue_Go() looks like this...

```
    function postValue_Go() {
        $.ajax({
            url: rootUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            method: 'POST',
            username: user,
            password: pass,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
```

*Here's the raw request, captured in Fiddler:*

```
POST http://someinternalserver:8888/api/Method/ HTTP/1.1
Host: someinternalserver:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 693
Accept: */*
Origin: http://devserver
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://devserver/samples/ExternalAPI/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: someCookieValue=Boo; someOtherCookieValue=Yum;

{"value1": "first value","value2": "second value"}
```

And the raw response, that too captured in Fiddler.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 19 Aug 2016 17:12:29 GMT
Content-Length: 61

{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

Comment: is this api return jsonp? and why you didn't add [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613815/callback-function-for-jsonp-with-jquery-ajax](jsonp callback). can you share screen, network->xhr?

Comment: If I change the data type from `JSONP` to `JSON` the question becomes an OPTIONS request.

Comment: JSONP is a GET request, that is how JSONP works.

Answer (score 0):

It's being sent as a GET request because JSONP appends a script to your webpage with the `src` attribute pointing to the web service (carrying out the GET request) which then returns the script with the requested data all bundled in a callback function.

Apparently it is possible to perform POST requests through JSONP if you're willing to do some serious leg work with iframes, etc. (see [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-calls-to-another-server-in-your-domain)), but for most intents and purposes you'll be limited to GET requests.

The authorization header is never set because there's currently no way to modify the headers sent for a script to be added to the page.

Comment: If I remove the `JSONP` the generated request becomes an `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: @amber I believe that's because you're setting custom headers. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)

Comment: That did something. I commented out the `beforeSend` handler, actually got a `POST`  but the server came back with a 401 Not Authorized. Looking at the raw request, I don't see any authorization information as set with the `user` and `password` setting value.

Comment: I believe the `user` field should be `username` and you might want to add `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true}` as well, but I'm not too sure about that.

Comment: Looking up the `Settings` for `$.Ajax`, you are correct, it should be `username`, so that's fixed. I added the xhrField you suggested. I'm still not seeing the authorization header in the request.