# python scrape webpage and parse the content

Tags: python, json, parsing, web-scraping, data-cleaning

I want to scrape the data on this link

http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/json/5491_historical.js?1453388629140&callback=return_json

I am not sure what type of this link is, is it html or json or something else. Sorry for my bad web knowledge. But I try to use the following code to scrape:

```
import requests

url='http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/json/5491_historical.js?1453388629140&callback=return_json'
source=requests.get(url).text
```

The type of the source is unicode. I also try to use the urllib2 to scrape like:

```
source2=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

The type of source2 is string. I am not sure which method is better. Because the link is not like the normal webpage contains different tags. If I want to clean the scraped data and form the dataframe data (like the pandas dataframe), what method or process I should follow/

Thanks.

Comment: @depperm, thanks for reply. I update the link. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The returned response is text containing valid JSON data within it. You can validate it on your own using a service like http://jsonlint.com/ if you want. For doing so just copy the code within the brackets

> return_json("JSON code to copy")

In order to make use of that data you just need to parse it in your program. Here an example: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: That's what I wrote. The content inside the brackets is the JSON data that you need. And it is valid. I validated it using the service I pointed out.

Comment: And I provided a code answer instead of a link. OP shouldnt need to copy that long response manually

Comment: I am not saying you need to copy the JSON response manually in your code. I was just trying to show that it is valid JSON. Just extract the JSON data from the response and do what you need in your code. If you need help handling json data from python I suggest you read the official docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: I don't need the link. I'm just saying your answer could be better (as in example code along with the link)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I now can confirm it is the json page.

Answer (score 0):

The response is text. It does contain JSON, just need to extract it

```
import json

strip_len = len("return_json(")

source=requests.get(url).text[strip_len:-2]
source = json.loads(source)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this method before but I don't know I should strip the 'return_json('. One comment, the correct code of 3rd line should be `source=requests.get(url).text[strip_len:-2]`, not -1.

Comment: I couldn't see the end of the response, but yes, you should strip that as it isn't part of the JSON

Comment: Basically, that URL is returning something that is meant to be queried by javascript, not python.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7613857/2308683