# Can I do a JSONP request with POST?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I'm trying to avoid jQuery and would like to use a native solution. How can I POST with JSONP?

Comment: No way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to avoid jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

JSONP works via inserting a `<script>` tag in the page, which then allows data to be retrieved from the remote server.  Obviously there's no way to `POST` a `<script>` tag.