# Cross-domain POST request ajax in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post, cross-domain

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and would like to make a POST request to another domain. It must be a POST request. But this does **not work in internet explorer** (I tried on IE9); it works on all other browsers.

I have this script:

```html
<script>
jQuery.support.cors = true;

jQuery(function() {
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain : true,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://someotherdomain/test.php',
        data: {},
        success: function(da) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(da))
        },
        error: function(jqxhr) {
            console.log('fail') 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqxhr))
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
</script>
```

I get back the error:

```js
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"Error: Access denied.\r\n"}
```

My PHP file looks like this:

```php
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
echo json_decode(array('success' => 'yes'));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) post request working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)

Comment: Relavent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12014195/545328

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149122/jquery-ajax-cross-domain-form-submission-issues-with-ie

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer (including IE9) does not support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). You have to proxy all your cross-domain request (post to PHP script on the same domain, that reposts with curl your query and returns the response)

Answer (score 2):

To support CORS in IE < 10, you must modify the ajax method to use the XDomainRequest object. This plugin does it for you: https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks

Answer (score 1):

Your script looks correct but I believe you need to change:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

to

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: x-requested-with');
```

or

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {Origin}');
```

Where {Origin} is the value of the Origin header. It's my understanding that just putting '*' won't work if an Origin has been given.

Also, IE8 and IE9 have limited support for this but it does work if you put `jQuery.support.cors = true`, as you've done.

Comment: so far as I know, `jQuery.support.cors` is read-only, for detection.

Comment: @theOther No, this can be set according to jQuery's doc: "cors is equal to true if a browser can create an XMLHttpRequest object and if that XMLHttpRequest object has a withCredentials property. To enable cross-domain requests in environments that do not support cors yet but do allow cross-domain XHR requests (windows gadget, etc), set $.support.cors = true;. CORS WD", http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Answer (score 0):

This works in IE9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var url = "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms759148(v=vs.85).aspx";
function getRequest() {
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); }
    catch (e) {alert("Error while getting 6.0");}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); }
    catch (e) {alert("Error while getting 3.0");}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    catch (e) {alert("Error while getting 2.0");}
    throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
};
var request = getRequest();
request.open("POST", url, false);
request.send();
alert("Content from :"+url+":"+ request.responseText);
</script>
</head>
<h1>AJAX ActiveX</h1>
```