# jQuery ajax cross domain form submission issues with IE

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I'm having a problem with IE, big surprise right?  I have a webform that submits name, phone, and email to a script that under another domain.  I'm jquery.ajax to submit the form.  I'm also using jquery.validate for form validation.  name and email are required.  phone is optional.

When I submit the form in Chrome, it works perfectly.  I receive my thank you email and my data reaches the script on the other domain.

When i try the same form in IE9, I fill in all fields and hit submit and it looks like its submitted (I receive the thank you message where the form is), but none of the data makes it to the service and I don't get a confirmation email either - so its not actually posting.

So how can i get this script to work in IE7,8,9.  Here's the script as it right now...When I uncomment the alert in the success action, I get the alert in IE.  It's just not posting the data. I've seen alot of posts on here about this, but I'm not getting all of the pieces together here in an understandle fashion.

I hear this works straight out of the box with IE10.

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
submitHandler: function() {

var cons_info_component = jQuery("#cons_info_component").val();
var cons_mail_opt_in = jQuery("#cons_mail_opt_in").val();
var longnum = jQuery("#1540_6383_2_8347_1").val();
var survey_id = jQuery("#SURVEY_ID").val();
var cons_email_opt_in = jQuery("#cons_email_opt_in").val();
var cons_email_opt_in_requested = jQuery("#cons_email_opt_in_requested").val();
var cons_first_name = jQuery("input#cons_first_name").val();
var cons_last_name = jQuery("input#cons_last_name").val();
var cons_email = jQuery("input#cons_email").val();
var cons_phone = jQuery("input#cons_phone").val();

if(cons_phone === "PHONE NUMBER (OPTIONAL)") { cons_phone = ''; }

var ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE = jQuery("#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE").val();

var dataString = 'cons_info_component='+cons_info_component+'&cons_mail_opt_in='+cons_mail_opt_in+'&1540_6383_2_8347='+longnum+'&SURVEY_ID='+survey_id+'&cons_first_name='+cons_first_name+'&cons_last_name='+cons_last_name+'&cons_email='+cons_email+'&cons_phone='+cons_phone+'&cons_email_opt_in='+cons_email_opt_in+'&cons_email_opt_in_requested='+cons_email_opt_in_requested+'&ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE='+ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE;


jQuery.ajax({   
type: "POST",
url: "http://urlthatIsubmittoo.com/script/",
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
data: dataString,

statusCode: {
404: function() {
  //alert('page not found');
},
200: function() {
  //alert('success');
}
},
 success: function() {
    //alert('submited');    
},
 complete: function() {

    jQuery('div.convioform').html("<div class='tybox'></div>"); 
    jQuery('div.convioform .tybox').html("<h5 class='webform-title'>Thank You</h5><p>You'll soon be receiving our e-mails and updates now.</p>");
        }
    }); // close .ajax line

},  
 });
```

Comment: @nathanhayfield: Always assuming those questions received acceptable answers. No one should accept answers that aren't acceptable just to keep their rate up.

Comment: good point, but i'm just saying

Comment: May I suggest that if you applied some sensible indenting to your code it would make it easier for us to follow and therefore easier to spot any problems?

Comment: Have you tried setting the data type to jsonp? Also why dont you use the standard jquery ajax response callbacks (success, error, etc)? You will always get a 200 if the ajax call even finds the post url. Getting a 200 doesn't mean that the request is actually completeing successfully.

Comment: I haven't tried setting the dataType to jsonp. I can remove the status code calls as well. Anything to do to make the script shorter. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this at the top of your file (via github/jaubourg):

```
if ( window.XDomainRequest ) {
    jQuery.ajaxTransport(function( s ) {
        if ( s.crossDomain && s.async ) {
            if ( s.timeout ) {
                s.xdrTimeout = s.timeout;
                delete s.timeout;
            }
            var xdr;
            return {
                send: function( _, complete ) {
                    function callback( status, statusText, responses, responseHeaders ) {
                        xdr.onload = xdr.onerror = xdr.ontimeout = jQuery.noop;
                        xdr = undefined;
                        complete( status, statusText, responses, responseHeaders );
                    }
                    xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                    xdr.onload = function() {
                        callback( 200, "OK", { text: xdr.responseText }, "Content-Type: " + xdr.contentType );
                    };
                    xdr.onerror = function() {
                        callback( 404, "Not Found" );
                    };
                    xdr.onprogress = jQuery.noop;
                    xdr.ontimeout = function() {
                        callback( 0, "timeout" );
                    };
                    xdr.timeout = s.xdrTimeout || Number.MAX_VALUE;
                    xdr.open( s.type, s.url );
                    xdr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
                },
                abort: function() {
                    if ( xdr ) {
                        xdr.onerror = jQuery.noop;
                        xdr.abort();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lyn for the answer. I'm going to try this right now.  Boy, do i hope it works!

Comment: Lyn, i tried putting that code right above this line: "jQuery.validator.setDefaults({" - it didnt seem to do anything.

Comment: ok, got my form to work in jsfiddle using a cross between your code and adding "dataType: "jsonp"," into the jquery. I'm going to try in my page next and hopefully all will be good in Denmark. Thanks!

Comment: ok this works in IE9, but its not removing the form and putting in the thank you message in the browser window...I'm gonna try to figure that out now. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: you're welcome, glad you're making progress. onward and upward!

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

This piece of shit came from MSIE has huge restrictions: cannot send headers, cannot use PUT and DELETE, cannot send content-type...