# Jquery Ajax method error with asp.net web service on a remote server subdomain

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, jquery

I created a project, it is an asp.net project and it has a Service1.asmx and ı hosted this project to remote server like a subdomain (**myservice.test.com/Service1.asmx**) and ı am calling this web service from an asp.net application with jquery ajax method. This application is on same remote server and ı hosted it like a subdomain (**admin.test.com**) when ı call admin.test.com/Default.aspx (this page uses web service abow) it is giving an error for this error ı looked with chrome console and it says: **(is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.)**4444

```
GET_CAT_ALL: function (userId, callback, callback_err) {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: myservice.test.com/Service1.asmx + "/GET_CAT_ALL",
            data: "{userId:" + userId + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d == "0" || msg.d.length == 0 || msg.d == null) {
                    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                        callback(null);
                    }
                }
                else if (msg.d <= 0) {
                    if (typeof callback_err == 'function') {
                        callback_err(msg.d, msg, 'GET_CAT_ALL');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    var _data = eval("(" + msg.d + ")");
                    if (typeof callback_err == 'function' && _data[0] != null && typeof _data[0].ErrorCode != 'undefined') {
                        callback_err(_data, msg, 'GET_CAT_ALL');
                    }
                    else if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                        callback(_data);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                if (typeof callback_err == 'function') {
                    callback_err(-1, msg, 'GET_CAT_ALL');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        if (typeof callback_err == 'function') {
            callback_err(-2, err, 'GET_CAT_ALL');
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: JSONP if you are using crossdomain also post some code or else random suggestions will come

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp

Answer (score 0):

This means that your subject to the Cross Side restrictions put in place by your browser. Consider using JSONP if you can to try and get around this issue or if you can guarentee your users are using more up to date browsers you could get around it by using headers on your webserver. Have a look at the [mozilla document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) about it.

Comment: did you switch both your output format and your ajax object to use JSONP?

Comment: ok so thats your JSON AJAX request code, but did you change your server to send out JSONP code rather than JSON code?

Comment: how can ı do this? It is a remote server on a host

Comment: If you don't have access to the remote server then I'm afraid your out of luck, you'd have to ask the remote server provider to support JSONP OR edit the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to be less restrictive.

Comment: is there any way with plesk panel?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13637/discussion-between-john-mitchell-and-mehmet)