# How to access the data from different server through AJAX call without JSONP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

I'm working on the project where the client has the back-end code in ServerA, and my front-end code, which is supposed to talk to back-end via AJAX requests is on ServerB, and they are in different domains. Because of the same origin policy, I'm not able to make those requests successfully (neither POST nor GET). Is it possible to enable it somehow without changing the back-end code to handle the JSONP? eg., white list that particular domain, or something?

I tried to emulate this in my local network where the back-end code is running on 10.0.1.4 (different machine), and I'm accessing it from localhost (apache), but couldn't figure out anything that doesn't require using jsonp. When calls are made, I'm not even seeing anything in the logs in the back-end, but it works fine from the REST client and by just loading the URL for GET requests. How are public API requests implemented that are not using JSONP?

I need at least one method (POST or GET) to work. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to enable it somehow without changing the back-end code
>   to handle the JSONP? eg., white list that particular domain, or
>   something?

Yes, you could write a server side script on your domain that will serve as a bridge between your and the remote domain and then send an AJAX request to your script.

Don't expect miracles. If you don't have control over the remote domain you are busted. The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction that's built into browsers for security reasons busts you. Well, you could always write your own browser that doesn't implement this policy, but I think you get my point.

Common workarounds include [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) but they involve control over the remote domain. If you don't have control then read the my previous sentence as well as my first sentence.

Here's a [nice guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) I invite you consulting that covers some common techniques allowing to achieve cross domain AJAX with jQuery. Then adapt the one that fits best your scenario. And there's always the heavy artillery solution that involves bridging the 2 domains with a server side script which works bullet-proof in 100% of the cases if none of the other workarounds help you.

Comment: Does that mean I can write my own server-side code, which acts like a bridge to the actual back-end code? `My HTML <=> My back-end <=> Client's back-end`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to enable it somehow without changing the back-end code to handle the JSONP? eg., white list that particular domain, or something?

Hmmm, mostly no. You must allow JSONP or "white list" things via [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (which is very easy to do). Or you can [use YQL as a cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax).

Answer (score 0):

Three solutions posted here:

http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/

I've tried the third option since it just worked for me.. and I didn't have to go through any extra stress as it just handled things just like a regular ajax call.

**Updating answer as this was posted 2 years ago:**

**LINK ABOVE NO LONGER WORKS.**

**Server side proxy:**

the old page also talks about using a server side proxy, which means your server makes a call to another server, grabs all the data and sends it off to a page resting on that server. There is no problem for one server to fetch data from another server. So then your page can make a regular ajax call to that server. I didn't go with this option as it required more manual labor. So I'd suggest going with the option detailed here:

**JSONP with jQuery**

1. Make sure the provider supports JSONP.
2. Set the dataType option to jsonp, and if the provider uses a different GET param other than 'callback', specify the jsonp option to that parameter name.

`$.ajax({
     // ... Use the AJAX utility as you normally would
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     // ...
 });`

jQuery will generate a unique callback name for this request (something like json1268267816). Thus, the reply from a web service would be something like:

```
json1268267816({'uid': 23, 'username': 'Chroder', 'name': 'Christopher Nadeau'});
```

But jQuery handles it all seamlessly, so you as the developer just handle it like a normal AJAX request using the same jQuery success/failure/complete callback hooks.

**Drawbacks:**

The first limitation to this method is that you have to rely on the provider to implement JSONP. The provider needs to actually support JSONP -- they need to wrap their JSON data with that callback function name.

Then the next limitation -- and this is a big one -- is that JSONP doesn't support POST requests. Since all data is passed in the query string as GET data, you are severely limited if your services require the passing of long data (for example, forum posts or comments or articles). But for the majority of consumer services that fetch more data than they push, this isn't such a big problem.

However,

Using a library like jQuery that supports JSONP, these details of inserting the special script tag and creating the special callback function are all taken care of automatically. Using a JS library, usually the only difference between JSONP and real AJAX is that you enable a 'jsonp' option.

Comment: devlog.info is no longer (or currently at least) not online, it leads to a godaddy parking page. :-(

Comment: I know it's been a month ago, but I updated my answer here, hope this help!