# $_POST returning {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

While trying to use:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: surl,
    data: {funcToCall: "getHello",val:"Luke"},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp : "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "getHelloResponse"

}).success(function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}).
    error( function (data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

I receive:

```
{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
```

But when leaving out the type which defaults type to "GET", it works fine!

The target php page was edited to handle POST and GET.

**EDIT:**

So the actual question is: why is the ajax post not returning the expected result of "Hello Luke!"?

Comment: You don't like http status code 200 `OK`?

Comment: I don't think using POST request alongside JSONP is a good idea. See, JSONP request is essentially `<script>` in disguise; but one does not simply specify a 'POST HTTP' as its src. Check [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp) for more details on this topic.

Comment: @LukeLindner Should I make this an answer for you to accept? ) Technically it's not an answer to your question, though; I don't know why `data` becomes `jqXhr` object.

Comment: @raina77ow Its up to you, but you did answer my question: don't use POST with jsonp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The success and error are expected as $.ajax settings, which return jqXhr, on which you can execute .done() for example, but not success or error.

Here is the working variant:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: surl,
    data: {funcToCall: "getHello",val:"Luke"},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp : "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "getHelloResponse",
    success: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    error: function (data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

This is done example, where if you can check if the execution is passed normally or something went wrong.. etc.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
    ($this).addClass("greenBody"); // This is the context - document.body
});
```