# What's causing the limit of 512 bytes - openkeyval or something else

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Hei!

I've found the superb service at http://openkeyval.org for storing simple key value from any webapps. From the docs it seems like it allows 64kBytes of data, put from what I see it's only possible to store 512 bytes.

See the example below (press load to load data from my key, and save to store back into key)

http://jsfiddle.net/larsi/h8Mbg/

Any ideas what might be causing the limit?

Regards Lars Erik

Comment: it works fine on my Chrome, what browser do you use?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Chrome. Did you try adding a few extra chars, so you exceed 512 length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are doing `GET` request instead of `POST`, to send a big portions of data you have to use `POST`. This code worked on my Chrome, but it could be only implementation of Chrome, so other browsers could not support such data transfer via `GET`

**update**

there is an issue regarding your problem and here is the link of existing issue on openkeyval's github:
https://github.com/shinyplasticbag/openkeyval/issues/14

Comment: Hmmm.. changing type into POST doesn't seem to change anything. Could it be that the service is truncating the data?

Comment: @Larsi I have also noticed that nothing changes, it still sends `GET` request. But I also found that changing datatype from "jsonp" to "json" makes jQuery to send `POST`. I have searched a little bit and found that it is not possible to send jsonp data to server via POST due to security limitations. Take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp

Comment: ok, I see. Then I guess there's some queryparams limits on the openkeyval.org site that is causing this.

Comment: maybe there is such limits, but also there is a limitation on `GET` query length by the browser

Comment: Oopps... found this: https://github.com/shinyplasticbag/openkeyval/issues/14 I've should have found this before asking. Looks like I have to wait for an update of that service. Thanks a lot for looking into it. I suggest you update your post with that link, and then I'll accept your answer