# Why are my KendoGrid "update" parameters always null in the controller?

Tags: c#, javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have the following code in my `Index.cshtml` file:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "json",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '@Url.Action("ReadTeachers", "EducationPortal")',
            dataType: "json"
        },
        update: {
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTeachers", "EducationPortal")',
            type: "POST"
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
            if (operation != "read"){ 
                var result = {};

                for (var i = 0; i < data.models.length; i++) {
                    var teacher = data.models[i];
                    for (var member in teacher) {
                        result["teacher[" + i + "]." + member] = teacher[member];
                    }
                }

                return result;
            } else {
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            }
        }
    },
    batch: true,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "TeacherId",
            fields: {
                TeacherId: { type: "number" },
                FullName: { type: "string" },
                IsHeadmaster: { type: "boolean" }
            }
        }
    }
});

$("#teachers").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    toolbar: ["create", "save"],
    columns: [
        { field: "FullName", title: "Teacher" },
        { field: "IsHeadmaster", title: "Is a Headmaster?", width: "120px" },
        { command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "85px" }],
    editable: true
});
```

This is a standard KendoGrid with "batch" editing. The editing and the grid itself both work fine, but the backend doesn't. When the "update" request goes through, it goes to this controller method:

```
public void UpdateTeachers(string models)
{
    // this method will have real code later
    Console.Write(models);
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in here, Visual Studio shows `models` to be `null`. Like so:

[image]

Why is it `null`?

Comment: Any console errors on browser? If not, try changing your arg name in the public void function from `models` to `result`.

Comment: It didn't help. No console errors, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your parameterMap: function ()

instead of using

```
return JSON.stringify(data);
```

use

```
return { models: kendo.stringify(data) };
```

here your data is serialize and attached to a name **models** now this name **models** is used as parameter name in your action

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the parameter in your controller inside of your parameter map function. Also it looks like you are trying to send the entire data object instead of the model. I would try this within your parameter map function:

```
parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
        if (operation === "update" && data.models){ 
            return {models: kendo.stringify(data.models) };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use .Batch(true) method inside .DataSource() in view of concerned action method
2. Use below code inside kendo grid to create toolbar

   ```
       .ToolBar(toolbar =>
       {
           toolbar.Create();
           toolbar.Save();
       })
   ```
3. Edit mode of grid must be incell to add add more than one entry or in batch mode like below sample code

   ```
      .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).TemplateName("EditDocket").Window(w => w.Title("Docket").Name("editWindow").Width(377).Height(200).Scrollable(true)))
   ```
4. Use below sample code to fetch model details binds to view in controller's action method

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult AppEditDocketCreate([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest  request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<UDocket> uDockets)
   {
       try
       {
           if (uDockets != null && ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               using (IVSourceEntities db = new IVSourceEntities())
               {

                   TBL_Docket tblDocket = new TBL_Docket();
                   foreach (var uDocket in uDockets)
                   {

                       tblDocket.DocketName = uDocket.DocketName;

                       tblDocket.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;

                       db.TBL_Docket.Add(tblDocket);
                       db.SaveChanges(); 
                   }

               }
           }
       }


      catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
       {

       }

       return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());

   }
   ```
5. Only thing that needed is [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable uDockets) as parameter to concerned action method