# Make a post called to servlet not get

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying get my Store to call the post method of my servlet but it keeps calling the get even though i set actionMethods to be post

```
Ext.define("Shows.store.Shows", {
extend: "Ext.data.JsonStore",
requires: "Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage",
config: {
    model: "Shows.model.Show",
    proxy: {
        type: 'scripttag',
        actionMethods: {
            create : 'POST',
            read   : 'POST', // by default GET
            update : 'POST',
            destroy: 'POST'
        },
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/GetShowsServlet',
        reader: {
         type: 'json',
         successProperty: 'success'
     },
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use POST with JSONP -- see [Post data to JsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp).  `actionMethods` is not configurable for `Ext.data.proxy.JsonP`