# Getting a 500 internet server error

Tags: .net, jquery, .net-3.5, asmx

I've got 2 intranet sites:

```
http://intranetv1/
http://intranetv2/
```

v1 is based on .NET 1.1, and v2 is based on .NET 3.5

On v1, I've created a webpage and I am trying to use some jQuery to access a webservice I created on v2.  As the webservices is coded using .NET 3.5, I can't have that webservices on v1.

Anyway, I assume I am supposed to make use of JSONP in this case, but each time I run the page, the ajax part does not work and in google chrome, I just get a 500 error message, as in cancelled.

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Here is the jQuery which is on the v1 .NET 1.1 server:

```
function selectedDateTime(strDate, strHours, strMinutes) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://intranetv2/webservices/meetingrooms.asmx/GetDayCount',
        data: '{ strMeetingDate:"' + strDate + " " + strHours + ":" + strMinutes + ":00" + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(department) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });

    return strDate + "---" + $("#txtDate").val();

}
```

As you can see, I am trying to access an .asmx file on the v2 .NET 3.5 server.

When I run this, google chrome gives me an 500 server error and says that the asmx file has been cancelled, and I then get an alert showing me the date alert at the end of the selectedDateTime function.  So the function is executing, but the success or error parts of the ajax script are not being executed at all.

---

I am getting the following response:

```
Request URL:http://intranetv2/webservices/meetingrooms.asmx/GetDayCount?callback=jQuery110100248512071557343_1372419413424&{%20strMeetingDate:%2228/06/2013%2006:00:00%22%20}&_=1372419413425
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Request Headers
GET /webservices/meetingrooms.asmx/GetDayCount?callback=jQuery110100248512071557343_1372419413424&{%20strMeetingDate:%2228/06/2013%2006:00:00%22%20}&_=1372419413425 HTTP/1.1
Host: intranetv3
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHYAAAAYABgAjgAAABIAEgBIAAAABgAGAFoAAAAWABYAYAAAAAAAAACmAAAABYKIogUBKAoAAAAPQgBQAEMATwBMAEwASQBOAFMAaQB4AGYASQBYAEYALQBHAEIASgBUAEIAMgBKAJBkNIpqc7C+AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIGOnhAoLt95s2HzXVTV7AvYOt1c9vbdJQ==
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://intranetv1/meeting/meeting_room_bookings_2_1.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
callback:jQuery110100248512071557343_1372419413424
{ strMeetingDate:"28/06/2013 06:00:00" }:
_:1372419413425

Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2013 11:36:57 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 406
```

---

Here is a screenshot of the error message I am getting in Google Chrome Developer Tools:
[image]
[Click here for full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehMfW.png).

---

Here is the .asmx code:

```
[WebMethod()]
public double GetDayCount(string strMeetingDate)
{
    string[] strDateAndTime = strMeetingDate.Split(' ');

    string[] strStartDateParts = strDateAndTime[0].Split('/');
    string[] srtStartTimeParts = strDateAndTime[1].Split(':');

    int year = Int32.Parse(strStartDateParts[2]);
    int month = Int32.Parse(strStartDateParts[1]);
    int day = Int32.Parse(strStartDateParts[0]);
    int hour = Int32.Parse(srtStartTimeParts[0]);
    int min = Int32.Parse(srtStartTimeParts[1]);
    int sec = Int32.Parse(srtStartTimeParts[2]);

    DateTime meetingDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
    {

        using (command = new SqlCommand("intranet.dbo.BusinessHours", connection))
        {

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@meeting_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = meetingDate;

            connection.Open();

            using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                return (double)reader["hours"];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `"As the webservices is coded using .NET 3.5, I can't have that webservices on v1."` - That statement is incorrect.  In any event, a 500 error indicates that something not-client-visible went wrong on the server.  What does your error handling on the server tell you?  Were any exceptions thrown in the web service?  Is there any kind of error message coming back in the response body?  (You may need to use browser debugging tools to see it.)  Also, what is the "date alert"?  `selectedDateTime()` returns a string value which contains a date, but it does so before any AJAX call returns anything.

Comment: Added the response header above. The alert was just a client side thing to see if the client script is actually reached, and it is. as it displays the date.

Comment: Is there a response body to go along with the headers?  Does that body contain an error message?  Even if it doesn't, what does the server-side error handling say?  Does the request make it into your code before it fails?  A 500 error means that something went wrong *on the server* so that's where the most relevant diagnostic information is going to be found.  As for the alert in question, that's always going to be reached because it happens *before* the AJAX call completes.  So "to see if the client script is actually reached" doesn't mean much, all it tells you is that JavaScript works.

Comment: Where on the server would I look?  I am using IIS6.

Comment: Depends on where the error is happening and how it's being logged.  If it's an exception that's being thrown from within the code and not being handled then you'll want to add some error handling to the code in order to log exceptions.

Comment: Check eventlog for more details.

Comment: @David, I've tried copying the .asmx file from the .NET 3.5 server to the .NET 1.1 server and it complains about missing libraries.

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski: No errors in: windows start > my computer > right click > manage > event viewer > applications.

Comment: Drag the request in fiddler to the composer tab, point it to localhost. Start the debugger for the service project, and execute the request. Let us know if it reaches the method, also check the response as it may know contain more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I can't use JSON-P plus POST...

> It is not possible to do an asynchronous POST to a service on another
>   domain, due to the (quite sensible) limitation of the same origin
>   policy. JSON-P only works because you're allowed to insert 
>   tags into the DOM, and they can point anywhere.

[Post data to JsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp)

Comment: If you control both domains, might be easier to set them up with the same base domain.  like intraanetv1.mysite.com and intranetv35.mysite.com.  Then you can set the document.domain and you should be good to go.

Comment: @oshirowanen, I don't see this as an acceptable 'answer', even though it is certainly relevant. If changing the request method (that is, the $.ajax property) to 'GET' worked, then that should be your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `strDate` has some invalid characters. So you need to encode the `strDate` value before sending through the ajax request.

***UPDATE***
Mark your web method as `ScriptMethod` like following

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public double GetDayCount(string strMeetingDate){}
```

read this for more information

http://tutorials.cmsnsoftware.com/2011/01/how-to-call-csharp-function-in-ajax.html

Comment: No errors in: windows start > my computer > right click > manage > event viewer > applications.

Comment: Try this `data: '{ strMeetingDate:"' + strHours + ":" + strMinutes + ":00" + '" }'`

Comment: You can always put a breackpoint on the service and see what is going on

Comment: that tutorial reference alone is worth +1

Answer (score 1):

remove comment from

```
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

this line in asmx.cs page

like

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Comment: It's not a project, it's a single .asmx file.  Can I still add a service reference?

Comment: uncomment this line in asmx.cs file => [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Answer (score 1):

You should do an ajax post back to some page in your own site and then do a request to whichever domain or service where you want the data from. 
You see the 500 error in chrome because there was an error in the webservice code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the date format.

Try changing it to `mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss` before making the call.

Comment: I'm already changing from `dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss` which is entered in client side, to `yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss` in the .asmx file

Comment: I've updated the question by adding my .asmx code which shows the data conversion to the bottom of my question.

Comment: Ok, just in your request header it is created like this: { strMeetingDate:"28/06/2013 06:00:00" }: which is dd/mm/yyy HH:MM:ss

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put localhost or whatever ip of your server.

http:// **localhost/** intranetv2/webservices/meetingrooms.asmx/GetDayCount

in url you used for webservice call

so replace it with

```
http://localhost/intranetv2/webservices/meetingrooms.asmx/GetDayCount
```

replace your function

```
function selectedDateTime(strDate, strHours, strMinutes) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/intranetv2/webservices/meetingrooms.asmx/GetDayCount',
        data: '{ strMeetingDate:"' + strDate + " " + strHours + ":" + strMinutes + ":00" + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(department) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });

    return strDate + "---" + $("#txtDate").val();

}
```

Comment: I don't need the localhost, as I can get to the intranet homepages using `http://intranetv1` or `http://intranetv2` when typed into a browser.

Answer (score 0):

There might be cross domain problem. Add files of crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml to virtual directory/website folder.

Code of crossdomain.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
  <cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction,Content-Type"/>
  </cross-domain-policy>
```

Code of clientaccesspolicy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
 <cross-domain-access>
  <policy>
   <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
     <domain uri="*"/>
   </allow-from>
   <grant-to>
     <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
   </grant-to>
 </policy>
 </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Alternatively you can also downloaded these files from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

**EDIT**
After reviewing your code minutely, I found that the problem is with passing date string.

As per your code output will be as

'{ strMeetingDate:"07/01/2013 17:10:00" }'

Whereas you need to generate date string value as below

'{ "strMeetingDate":"07012013 17:10:00" }'
OR
'{ strMeetingDate:07012013 17:10:00 }'

That means strMeetingDate property should be of string type.

This can be viewed when you see the help of asmx service. It provides help as we have in WCF service.

Comment: Can you change the datatype to json from jsonp and add these xml files to it?

Comment: Changed `jsonp` to `json` and I am now getting a `403 forbidden` message.  Which server gets the .xml files?  v1, or v2?

Comment: Place it at the location where your service is hosted. This will let the service invoked from other website (or other domain)

Comment: Copied the files to the same server/directory which contains the .asmx file, and I still get a 403 forbidden message.

Comment: Try after editing your code to below format data: '{ "strMeetingDate":"' + strDate + " " + strHours + ":" + strMinutes + ":00" + '" }'. i.e. strMeetingDate in between quotes

Comment: @ChiragVidani I think your answer here applies to a WCF service, where as the OP is attempting to use a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following in your web.config inside **system.web**

```
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

Also if you encounter a missing parameter error, try to change your data into this:

```
data: "strMeetingDate=" + strDate + " " + strHours + ":" + strMinutes + ":00",
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you control both domains, might be easier to set them up with the same base domain.  like intraanetv1.mysite.com and intranetv35.mysite.com.  Then you can set the document.domain = mysite.com and the same origin policy should be relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

If you control both domains, might be easier to set them up with the same base domain.  like intraanetv1.mysite.com and intranetv35.mysite.com.  Then you can set the document.domain = mysite.com and the same origin policy should be relaxed.

Another option is Cross Origin Resource Sharing or CORS.  Here is an article on it:  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/understanding-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors.html

Answer (score 0):

Use (Configure & implement) CORS, and send your content as 'application/xml'

> With the emergence of the Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)
>   specification, now a candidate for W3C Recommendation, web application
>   developers have a browser-supported mechanism to make XmlHttpRequests
>   to another domain in a secure manner.

http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/

Review: CORS support Client (browsers/user-agents)
http://enable-cors.org/client.html

Review: CORS support SERVER
http://enable-cors.org/server.html