# Json request to another domain

Tags: php, jquery, json

Im trying to make a request from one server to another with json and php.

my html page:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://api.domain.com/gateway/partners/create_account.ajax.php",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: { "name" : "Test name"},
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data.responseText);
            }
          });
```

My php looks like this:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$data = array("Hello", $name);

echo json_encode($data);
```

I want to receive on my console: Hello Test name

What did I do wrong?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You can't use JSONP and POST request:

See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are:

1. Telling jQuery to process the response as JSONP
2. Writing PHP that will output JSON (not JSONP) … presumably with a `text/html` content-type.
3. Trying to make a POST request instead of a GET request. JSONP only supports GET.
4. Trying to treat the data returned by the request as if it were an XHR object.

The minimal example of a JSONP response would be:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
$name = $_GET['name'];
$data = array("Hello", $name);

echo $_GET['callback'];
echo "(";
echo json_encode($data);
echo ");";
```

Then you need to alter the JS so that `type: "POST"` becomes `type: "GET"` and `console.log(data.responseText);` becomes `console.log(data);`

Alternatively, you could use [another technique to bypass the same origin policy](/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) and still use POST.

Answer (score 0):

The jsonp is a old practice and a insecure one because any one can call to your script. To is very default tor retrieving errors when a jsonp call fails.

You can implement [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers in your request, and then you can use just a simple XHR call.

Addeding the header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Will fix your issue, but is better use the exact domain instead of the wildcard.