# Error in calling jsonrpc service in jquery

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a jsonrpc web service which is deployed on my redhat linux AMI. I can access this service in python as given below:

```
>>> import jsonrpclib
>>> server=jsonrpclib.Server(redhat_linux_ami_jsonrpc)
>>> x=server.addmicroelement('test test test')
>>> x
u'first insert'
```

where , redhat_linux_ami_jsonrpc = jsonrpc service hosted on redhat linux AMI

But when I try to call it in jquery, it works in IE but fails in Firefox. The code I have written is given below:

```
    var req = {jsonrpc:'2.0', method: 'addmicroelement',id:(new Date).getTime()}; 
    req.params=['new new new'];
    $.support.cors = true;      
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        url: redhat_linux_ami_jsonrpc,
        data: JSON.stringify(req),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(rpcRes) {
          alert(rpcRes.result); 
        },
        error: function(err, status, thrown) {
          alert(status);
        }  
    });
```

where , redhat_linux_ami_jsonrpc = jsonrpc service hosted on redhat linux AMI.
It says "Cross-Origin Request Blocked". How to resolve this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I see an alert box displaying "error". Its the alert(status); statement.

Comment: Why don't you see what you are getting in `err` and `thrown` variables?

Comment: It shows [object Object] for 'err', error for 'status' and empty text for 'thrown'.

Comment: If you do `console.log(err);`, it will show you the complete `err` object with it's properties.

Comment: I did it but there is nothing which could explain the reason for error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59487/discussion-between-gliese-581-g-and-p5coder).

Comment: @P5Coder:{readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "No Transport"}

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that cross-domain requests like this are no longer allowed for security reasons.

A possible solution is using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), though I don't yet have experience with this:
http://enable-cors.org/
(Obtained from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18509333/1245352)

Another possibility is to use `{dataType: 'jsonp'}`, which is JSON with padding.  Unfortunately, this automatically sets your request to a `'GET'` instead of a `'POST'`, which is what you're currently using.  A possible workaround is to change your webservice to use the `'GET'` method instead.  There are also a bunch of hacks to post data to jsonp: [Post data to JsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp)

You can also try using `curl` wrapped by a php script to make the request, and return the results.