# Angular JS `$http` sends POST instead of GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp, angularjs-http

This code,

```
$http.jsonp('http://localhost:3000/students?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',{
                data:student,
                method:'POST'
})
```

sends a GET request instead of a POST request. 
Rails log:

```
Started GET "/students?callback=angular.callbacks._1" for ::1 at 2015-03-28 
20:07:30 -0500
Processing by StudentsController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"callback"=>"angular.callbacks._1"}
  Student Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `students`.* FROM `students`
  Rendered students/index.jpbuilder (2.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JSONP` requests can only be `GET` requests. I'd have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699351/2010925) post detailing why this isn't possible.