# Angular $http.jsonp() method works only once

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, jsonp, angular-http

Response is succeded (alert->done), but second and another hits will response 'error'.

I've tried to add some config params with 'cache: false' but still works only first time. Should I clear some cache/history or sth?

```
    $scope.add2 = function() {

    var config = {
        //url : 'http://www.***.pl/index.php/json/getallusers',
        cache: false,
        //type : 'POST',
        crossdomain: true,
        //callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
        //data: d,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
    };

            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 4;
            var d = {user_type_id:0, user_venue_id:0, fname:r}; 
            var e = objToString(d);


//$http.jsonp('http://www.***.pl/index.php/json/adduserget?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&'+ e, config)

$http.jsonp('http://www.***.pl/index.php/json/adduserget?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&'+ e)
                .success(function(res){
                    console.log('res:' + res.user); 
                    alert('done');
                })
                .error(function(){  
                    console.log('error');       
                    alert('error');
                }); 
        };
```

This is the new question in  [jsonp and post action in ionic framework (angular.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496842/jsonp-and-post-action-in-ionic-framework-angular-js)

I've added to server response 'angular.callbacks._0(' before json data... maybe here's mistake?

This is solution for my issue:
now i'm dynamiccaly getting the callback parameter which can by vary (not always angular.callback_0, but can be: angular.callback_1, angular.callback_2, etc.) from GET method at a server and put it before response data f.e in php:

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json;');
$json=json_encode($result);
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.$json.')';
?>
```

Comment: from where are you calling it, can you provide the code?

Comment: I'm using with ionic frm, here's sinppets: http://codepen.io/studentttt/pen/BNPPoP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is because url is getting cached in browser and the other time it will fetch from the cache.So I'd suggest you to add new dummy parameter inside you `URL` that will have current `Date.now()` so that every time you call service that will make `URL` unique doe to `Date.now()` component.

**Code**

```
$http.jsonp('http://www.where2play.pl/index.php/json/adduserget?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&'+
 e + '&dummy='+ Date.now()) //<--this will add new value everytime to make url unique
```

Comment: I've tried this and happen the same, strangest thing is: every request finishes with a 200 and the same repsonse, but $http jumps into error case

Comment: exactly,so why it goes to ?