# passsing data to https by JSON using JSONP

Tags: json, ajax, highcharts, https, jsonp

i had try many diffrent tutarials and examples from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and [Post data to JsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp) and saw many staffs about how to convert json data to jasonP but still i can not do it,is there any one could see how should i pass my data over https within my codes here which i am using highcharts to get data from my domain sql server which is in diffrent server than my webpages host.here is my codes:(i know which i should use ajax request but i dont know how in my case,if anyone know please HELP!) tnx.

getting data by getJASON over data.php which request from sql server to grab data:

```
  var Options;
  $(document).ready(function() {

     Options = {
      chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
            type: 'area',
            borderColor: "#3366ff",
            borderWidth:5,
            zoomType : 'x'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Total Meeting_Logs Duration of Organization1 '
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ' '
    },
    credits:{
        enabled:false
     },

        xAxis: {
            categories: [],
            labels: {
                align: 'center',
                x: -3,
                y: 20,
             //format data based on #datepicker which is html jquery ui date     
            //picker
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p',   
          Date.parse(this.value +' UTC'));
                }
            }
         },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 3
   },


  // Enable for both axes
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: [true,true]
      },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },

        series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: '',
                data: []
       }]
    }
           // here i get my data from data.php within same server

    $.getJSON("data.php", function(json){
        Options.xAxis.categories = json['category'];
        Options.series[0].name = json['name'];
        Options.series[0].data = json['data'];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(Options);
      });

    });
                  //this function get user request for input time period and 

                //update in my domain
    $(function() {
     $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $.getJSON("data.php?dateparam1="+dateText, function(json){
            Options.xAxis.categories = json['category'];
            Options.series[0].name = json['name'];
            Options.series[0].data = json['data'];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(Options);
        });
      }
    });
    });
```

data.php:
      `

```
    if (!$con) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
               }

       mysql_select_db("moh1368_Mrs_Lemoine", $con);

      if (isset($_GET["dateparam"])) {

       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT timestamp_value, traffic_count FROM  

   foot_traffic WHERE timestamp_value LIKE '".$_GET["dateparam"]."%'");
          } else {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT timestamp_value, traffic_count FROM 
     foot_traffic        WHERE timestamp_value LIKE '2013-02-01%'");
       }
     $result['name'] = 'Foot Traffic Count';
     while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $datetime = $r['timestamp_value'];
     $result['category'][] = $datetime;
     $result['data'][] = $r['traffic_count'];
      }

      print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

     mysql_close($con);
     ?>`
```

Comment: Any chance to use the punctuation in your question? It is really hard to understand what exactly you have and what you need right now..

Comment: i found some solution from highcharts but i am not sure how to use it : http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/getting-data-across-domains-jsonp

Comment: @PawełFus i will point where i need to change to get result

Comment: @PawełFus i had added comments data flows happens in this example,is that fine? actually i found one example from highchart which is here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/getting-data-across-domains-jsonp ,but i am confuse how to use it.

Comment: One of these surely must help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+return+jsonp .

Comment: Two things: 1) your `$.getJSON("data.php",...)` is missing `?callback=?` 2) Your PHP is not adding callback encapsulation: `echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($array) . ')'; `